# How can I have a list item from another host name site collection open in a modal dialog and function properly

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

Good Afternoon. I am using a Content search web part to pull list information from a different site collection and provide the results in a modal pop up. I have been able to accomplish displaying the data using:

```
'<a href='#' onclick='SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog("_#= linkURL =#_")'>Open Modal</a>'
```

In my display template `linkURL` is the address for the item to be displayed.

The items from the other site collection show in the modal pop up, but the ribbon buttons and the close buttons do not seem to be working.

I am using the same display template for a list in the same site collection and it works perfectly.

Any ideas why it is breaking across site collections?